# LNK1104 :cannot open file libboost_date_time-vc

Tags: boost

Currently I m working on client-sever program, I uses CROW microframework  to create server site. The reason of this is because CROW was written in C plus plus language and also  I m familiar with c plus plus, Next, this CROW microframework require BOOST this library to execute, So, I have followed this  , I have  done what need to be done to make sure my program can execute with the boost libraries. I have written my code in notepad++ . here my codes :

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include "crow.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "hello world";

   return 0;
}


#endif
```

Moreover, I uses DEVELOPER command prompt that provided by VS2015 to compile my program .[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21LRN.jpg)

I have spent hours to google why am I getting that error, eventually none of the resource from google is working. Someone from here please tell what is the solution to the error? Your help will be appreciated!

[image_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0On8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this looks like a linking problem, meaning that your CROW library is not linked properly to Boost. So, how to do that and make sure it works, here is a guide `(for msvc2013 users)`.

**Requirements :**

- Install boost (No need to install it manually as precompiled [binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/) exist, I recommend 1.60.0, choose one according to your toolset (msvc2013) and architecture (32/64 bits). Not sure, use [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.60.0/boost_1_60_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe/download) )
- Download [CROW](https://github.com/ipkn/crow) source code from github.
- Download and install [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) (version > 2.8)

**Installation steps :**

- Extract CROW_source in a folder we will call it `Crow_folder`.
- create a /build folder inside your Crow_folder`.
- Open CMake and `set the source folder as your Crow_folder and the build folder to the Crow_folder/build` (that you have just created).

Here's a screenshot : 
[image]

**Linking Boost to Crow :**

Now, hit configure, and choose the architecture :

Here, just use the same architecture as your boost.

- Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -> boost 64 bits
- Visual Studio 12 2013 -> boost 32 bits

here's a screenshot of the dialog :

[image]

Click on `Add Entry` , a dialog will be brought up and add the following entries :

- NAME : BOOST_ROOT | TYPE : PATH | VALUE : Boost_Install_Dir(sth like C:/Local/Boost_1_60)
- NAME : BOOST_LIBRARYDIR | TYPE : PATH | VALUE : Boost_Install_Dir/lib64_msvc-12.0(sth like C:/Local/Boost_1_60/lib64_msvc-12.0/)

[image]

**Generate :**

Now, hit `configure`. If everything is OK, it will be successful !
Now that your project is configured, hit `Generate`.

**Test :**

In your `Crow_folder/build` , an `msvc project` will be created and containing the [Crow example](https://github.com/ipkn/crow/blob/master/examples/example.cpp). Open that project and build it. and hopefully, it will be successful.

**Congratulations**, now, you can use CROW.

[image]

**PS:** `this worked for msvc2013, not msvc2015`. (It looks like it won't work with it anyway, for now due to lambda problems as [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2582608/c-14-internal-compiler-error-when-mixing-generic-lambdas-and-template-member-functions) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1396868/msvc-2015-crashes-when-faced-with-lambda-expression-in-function-parameter-array-bounds))

Comment: Hey , Thank you for the feedback. I had tried the solution that you suggested. However, i still cant run example program, I kept getting this error LNK2019 unresolved external sysmbol"class boost::system::call.....       any idea on solving this issues? thanks

Comment: did anything in the `configure` or `generate` go wrong during the process ? did you choose the same architecture ( 64 / 32 bits) as the boost binaries while choosing the CMake compiler tool at the beginning. Anyway, that still a boost linking problem !

Comment: Hi Vtik, in order to see what is going on with the process of CMAKE, I have attached a picture in the question, click on RESULT OF THE CMAKE in the question box for further details. Thanks

Comment: Well, everything looks fine for me ! now, let's `make sure that the same architecture is used`. In `boost`, which extension did you have as your `boost/library_dir "lib64" or 32 bits` ? you just have to use the `same` as the compiler tool architecture (when you first hit configure) ? That won't show up in the screenshot you took ! Just to make sure of that, you will need to delete `CMake cache` and restart all the linking boost instructions. I will edit my answer according to that

Comment: Okay, I think I'm using different compiler tool architecture and "lib64" exist in boost/library/dir . What should I do to make sure I m using the same compiler tool architecture ? Thanks

Comment: Delete the cach using `CMake - File -> Delete cache` action button in menu. hit `Configure`, the choosing dialog will show up, choose  `Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64` from the list. that should do the trick, add again the entries as described and follow the rest of the answer...

Comment: Hi Vitik, I m really appreciate the solution that you had suggested, I have followed all the guideline that you provided, however I am still unable to run  the example program successfully , still getting error, please refer to the image in the question box. Please continue to guide me as in I feel like we are almost getting this program done but we still have some issues that we need to solve it quickly . Thanks

Comment: Oh, no !! that's my friend is  a bug in msvc 2015. it's been reported here with lambda function and some others are also related. For my case, that just worked fine for msvc2013, didn't try the msvc2015. So, for now, if 2015 is not compulsory, just roll back to 2013. sorry for that ! :)

Comment: Hi vitik, still cannot run the example program successfully despite i already "rolled back" to VS 2013. Please go this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37246953/crow-microframework-issues    for further details. Thanks

Comment: if you change your toolset, you should also change the boost library accordingly and the build tool in cmake. Restart from the begin of the answer using only (64 bits) with msvc 2013. and refollow it. if anything happen, leave me a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the response. First, i lunch CMake-GUI, then hit confgure, pop up a dialog, I choosed Visual Studio 12 2013 Win 64 then click on finish. After that I filled in the entries. Next i clicked on configure . That what i done so far in the cmake process.This approach will give me error, I already attached a screenshot in the question. FYI, If I choose VS 14 2015, everything is fine . Fine as in the i can generate file through CMAKE, but still cannot build.Thanks

Comment: that meaning that he cannot find the library_dir of boost. make sure to use boost msvc2013 64bits and fill the entries with the correspondent folder ! It would be better if your delete CMake Cache and restart from the installation steps. do it clean this time ;)

Comment: i followed every detail of your instructions already. still having the same error. regarding to the boost library , i tried two directory ,first one is C:\local\boost_1_60_0\lib64-msvc-14.0     and the 2nd one is C:\local\boost_1_60_0\libs   .Both of the directory did not work out eventually. FYI , currently i have two visual studio installed in my com namely VS 2013 and VS 2015

Comment: HI , you mentioned "It would be better if your delete CMake Cache and restart from the installation steps." This installation steps is regarding to ?

Comment: **installation steps :** from the answer

Comment: hey, this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.60.0/boost_1_60_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe/download) will get you all the binaries, you won't need to install boost yourself. Just download the .exe end execute it. no b2 no bjam nor whatever. you'll need another tutorial for that, not covered in my answer. So, just install the binaries and that's the all of it. then, Go to CMake and configure your project .....

Comment: Hey, I already tried many times, stillnot working out. is it because there is 2 visual studio installed in the same comp?

Comment: for my case, I only have msvc2013 installed. I answered your question based on a test I've done myself when i wanted to answer your question. It worked as a charm since the first time. Now, it could be that two msvc versions are messing up sth, but I'm not sure. Sorry, but that was the best I can and I grant you that the answer above is what you need to do to get it working. (see the pic in the end of the answer)

Comment: if you have a teamviewer account, get me the access and maybe i can help ... (if you want to of course :) )

Comment: Hi Vtik, I really appreciate your help! Everything is working out now! I downloaded the wrong file. Right now, it can be build! but cannot cannot rn the program , error said cannot find the file specified,I have already build the solution couple of time already. oh yeah! just so you know, i did all of these process after unistalling VS'15, so i m not sure that VS is overlapping and cause so much trouble to me. Thanks!

Comment: HI vitik, just curious , can i compile through command prompt? I mean can write the code in notepad++ and compile with cmd prompt . Can it be done ?Thanks

Comment: It could ne done, Post à new question on SO i'll see you there ;)

Comment: Hi, I already posted a new question regarding to compile the program with cmd. Here's link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265823/linker-errorcrow-microframework                                                                                                  giving you a heads up first about the new question. Thanks