# LINKER error::CROW microframework

Tags: c++, boost

I uses [CROW](https://github.com/ipkn/crow) this micro framework to create a server site. First of all, I started to write a simple code with a Notepad++ , such as like this:

```
#include "crow.h"

int main()
{

return 0;
}
```

I save it as .cpp file and save it inside "include" folder along with other header file.

After that, I tried to compile the code via developer command prompt with such command as like this :

```
cl /EHsc /I C:\local\boost_1_60_0  C:\Users\USER\Desktop\crow-master\include\example.cpp ^ /link /LIBPATH:C:\local\boost_1_60_0\lib64_msvc-12.0
```

This approach will give linker error  with a message saying cannot open file (...).lib .

Am I doing the right way? 
Did I miss out something ? 
Please tell me what should I do to improve this situation.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Included the dangling `}` in the code. Formatted `cl` command as code. Broke text into new lines.  Made a guess on the framework location for the hyperlink(couldn't find a tag).